# JScrollPane: Disable Scroll-by-dragging

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, drag

I am using some JGraphX components but this question can be applied to a general purpose of java.

I have a component inside of a JScrollPane. The issue I am having is that I have the ability to pan in the view by "grabbing" the view and moving it around like Google maps. but if the cursor leaves the viewport the scrolling changes directions. I have done some research and found the issue causing the problem. It can be found part of the way down on this page where it starts talking about how the scrollpane works.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

> Move the cursor over the image and press the cursor. Continuing to
>   press the cursor, drag to a point outside the image and pause. The
>   visible area of the image moves toward the cursor. This
>   scroll-by-dragging functionality is enabled by the scroll pane, and
>   with the JComponent API, but it is implemented by the custom component
>   that displays the image.

It has the little demo so you can see how it works as well as the code is available for download.

So by default the scrollpane has a scroll to drag implemented but it is actually opposite of how I need mine to scroll. The JGraphX library I am using has extended most of the classes used to benefit itself in some way but the basic idea still applies. I really just need to know of the easiest way to disable this. Yhe page says its enabled by the scrollpane and the JComponent API, but what actually gets enabled?

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I have literally gone through every class that could possibly set autoscrolls to true and set it to false. but in the end, no dice. I have already tried to fix the mouse listeners up for how i need them... also no dice. i came here because i like the people here better and you guys are much more knowledgeable but i guess ill have to wait for a response over there. :( i originally thought that the autoscrolls was the issue too. but no matter where i set it to false it still does it

Comment: Man, that sounds pretty annoying. Maybe you should get all the Mouse(Motion)Listeners from both the scroll pane and the contained component and just print out a list. See how many there are of each type. Then try removing them and see what (if anything) still happens. If you lose the ability to scroll by dragging outside of the viewport, then one of those mouse listeners has to be the culprit. Could you tell us what component class you've got in the pane? And if there's anything else in there? Maybe we can simulate it locally and experiment a bit.

Comment: the layout of the Jgraphx stuff is pretty confusing. if you are familiar with it this will be probably more clear for you. but i have a class that extends jpanel that has a class that extends their mxGraphComponent. mxGraphComponent extends jScrollpane.

so far so good. but heres where it gets confusing. i dont actually see a component. it has a canvas class that would appear to do all the rendering but i really dont know. it also has an mxGraph object that appears to just handle events. but neither of them are actually from the component class. its been awhile since i have looked at this code

Comment: mxGraphComponent has a class that extends jcomponent called mxGraphControl. but i set its autoscrolls to false with no change in the end...

Comment: i removed all the listeners from the mxGraphComponent that i didnt create and it now works as i wanted! thank you much!

Comment: Well, the danger there is that by simply removing them you could break some wanted functionality. You might want to try my suggestion of wrapping the MouseMotionListeners in a proxy that intercepts the mouseDragged method and ignores it under some circumstances. It's more work, but could be a clean approach with less chance of wrecking other stuff accidentally.

Comment: yeah i went through and found the listener that was causing the issue. changed its functionality (read: removed to lines) and all is good in the world. ill put what i did in the answers part

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but I think you need to use:

```
component.setAutoscrolls( false );
```

Answer (score 2):

[This method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAutoscrolls%28boolean%29) from `JComponent` looks like the best starting point to investigate. You could retrieve the component in your scroll pane and call that method with `false` on it. That's the default, but it's possible JGraphX has it enabled by default.

Alternatively, you could get the `MouseListener`s and/or `MouseMotionListener`s from the scroll pane and replace them with something that overrides the dragging behaviour. Since those are interfaces, you could use [proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) objects for that. Seems somewhat hacky, though.